# Suggest some good note on harmonic measure

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, harmonic-analysis

Can someone please suggest some good book or lecture note on harmonic measure? Thanks in advance.

Now I am reading The logarithmic integral I by Paul Koosis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also take look at the book "Harmonic Measure" by John Garnett and Donald Marshall.

And may be at "Potential theory in the complex plane" by Thomas Ransford for related concepts.

Answer (score 3):

Try either Ahlfors, "*Conformal Invariants - Topics in Geometric Function Theory*", Chapter 3 (entitled "Harmonic measure"), or Conway, "*Functions of One Complex Variable, Vol. II*", Chapter 21 (entitled "Potential Theory in the Plane"). Both are quite standard texts in complex analysis, you may want to have a look at them! ;-)